# Lineplot with color, line style, and marker style as data dimension

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, line-plot

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

| time | performance | attr_c | attr_s | attr_m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | C1 | S1 | M0 |
| 1 | 15 | C1 | S0 | M1 |
| 2 | 9 | C1 | S1 | M2 |
| 3 | 12 | C2 | S0 | M0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Time and performance are numbers, all attributes are categories. Each combination of attributes does occur several times.

I would like to use seaborn to plot the performance over time with a line plot. I also want to see the state of all attributes at each data point to visualize any correlations.
However, with a naive line plot I can, as far as I can see, only use color and style as data dimensions, but I want to use line and marker style as two dimensions:

```py
sns.lineplot(data=df,
             x='time',
             y='performance',
             hue='attr_c',
             style='attr_s',
             # markers='attr_m' # this does not work!
             )
```

So in the end I would like, for each unique combination of attributes, a line with a unique combination of color (`attr_c`), line style (`attr_s`), and marker style (`attr_m`). And a legend of course :)

Answer (score 0):

You could plot twice: once for the lines and once for the markers (`style=` refers both to linestyle and to markers). `markers=None` suppresses the markers.  The linestyles are a bit more stubborn, to suppress them, `dashes=[...]` can be set to lines of 0 long with gaps of 1.

This creates a double legend.  Counting the number of elements expected in the legend, the interesting parts of the legend can be recombined.

The following example adapts seaborn's tips dataset:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
# let 'step' be the order sorted by 'tip'
tips['step'] = np.argsort(np.argsort(tips['tip'])) 
attr_c = 'day'
attr_s = 'sex'
attr_m = 'time'
len_c = len(tips[attr_c].unique())
len_s = len(tips[attr_s].unique())
len_m = len(tips[attr_m].unique())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
# lineplot with linestyles, without markers
sns.lineplot(data=tips, x='step', y='total_bill',
             hue=attr_c, style=attr_s,
             markers=None, ax=ax)
# lineplot with only markers
sns.lineplot(data=tips, x='step', y='total_bill',
             hue=attr_c, style=attr_m, markers=['^', 'v'], ms=10,
             dashes=[(0, 1)] * len_m, ax=ax)
ax.margins(x=0.01) # less whitespace left and right

# grab entries of existing legend and recombine them
handles = ax.legend_.legendHandles
labels = [t.get_text() for t in ax.legend_.texts]
ax.legend(handles=handles[:1 + len_c + 1 + len_s] + handles[-(1 + len_m):],
          labels=labels[:1 + len_c + 1 + len_s] + labels[-(1 + len_m):],
          loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), frameon=False)
sns.utils.adjust_legend_subtitles(ax.legend_)  # seaborn usually left aligns subtitles

sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.lineplot with both linestyles and markers]